# Concerning parent/child array relationship

Tags: php, arrays, loops, parent

This is my database structure:

[image]

I would like to loop through all the child elements (those who's parent_id is set to the data_id within the same table).
Therefore those with "parent_id" as "0" are parents, and those with parent_id with a number in it is a child.

I would like help creating a function that will generate tables, with the table itself as the parent, and all the rows within it would be children of that parent. There is only one layer of depth in this project (one parent and one child layer always. ).

Can anyone help, or would want a more detailed description?

Thank you, and looking forward to a reply.

Comment: you can do a single loop and check whether the parent_id is 0 or not. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: If i were to do a loop to select the parent, then do a loop inside that to get all the children, it seems very un-optimized and that is what I am using right now. I am building a project with quite a bit of data fields so I am seeking most optimized method of doing this. Thank you for the edit btw, I am unable to post images until my reputation is higher than 10

Comment: How would your data in your database? If it is 1st - parent, 2nd- child of 1st, 3rd- parent, 4th - child of 3rd, then you don't need to run 2 loop? Or you can loop 1 time only, and create table with data_id as an id if parent_id is 0. If parent_id is != 0, createElement and append it to the table with the ID you have create. Just make sure the parent has to be created first

Comment: Can you show me how that is done? I think I understand what you're saying but I can't put it quite to code just yet.

Comment: I will try to put a pseudo code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, as when I look at your database, I assume that your parent will always be added before your child is (If I am wrong, please correct me). And because you said that you only have 1 parent and 1 child, I believe this is how your database would look like:

```
1st - parent
2nd - child of 1st
3rd - parent
4th - child of 3rd
```

If that's the case, one single loop can help you out with this pseudo code

```
//get the data from the database
//run through the loop
//check if the parent_id is 0
//   if it is, create an element (a table) to be the container with the id as cited in your data_id
//   if is is not, create an element (a row). Then append this element to the table with the same id as this parent_id
```